# Is it possible to express the type of (Type,Value) pairs on Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

Lists of (Type,Value) pairs can be expressed on Idris as:

```
data List : Type where
  Cons : (t : Type ** t) -> List -> List
  Nil  : List

example : List
example = Cons (Nat ** 3) (Cons (Bool ** True) Nil)
```

What is the syntax to express those on Haskell?

Comment: Is the type being represented at runtime?

Comment: You can't quite say it in Haskell because it's not dependently typed (you can't put types in a value-level list) but the Idris definition you gave is functionally equivalent to `data List = forall a. Cons a List | Nil` because types are opaque in Idris.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that if you construct such `List` you cannot do anything with the
elements, as you cannot pattern match on the types.

However it's entirely possible in Haskell usign `GADTs`

```
data List where
    Cons :: t -> List -> List
    Nil  :: List

example :: List
example = Cons (3 :: Int) (Cons True Nil)
```

You *can* extend that with a constraint, e.g. `Typeable` so you get
run-time type information to do things on elements in the list:

```
data CList (c :: * -> Constraint) where
    CCons :: Typeable t => t -> List c -> List c
    CNil  :: CList c

exampleC :: CList Typeable
exampleC = CCons (3 :: Int) (CCons True CNil)
```

Or you can use `HList`

```
data HList (xs :: [*]) where
    HCons :: x -> List xs -> List (x ': xs)
    HNil  :: '[]

exampleH :: HList '[Int, Bool]
exampleH = HCons 3 (HConst True HNil)
```

---

In particular dependent pairs (or sums!) ([Idris docs](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#dependent-pairs)) are possible with in Haskell to,
Yet we have to make a GADT for a function!
The http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-sum is one many use

If Idris version is

```
data DPair : (a : Type) -> (P : a -> Type) -> Type where
   MkDPair : {P : a -> Type} -> (x : a) -> P x -> DPair a P
```

the Haskell is not that much different when `a = Type`:

```
data DPair (p :: * -> *) where
   MkDPair :: p a -> DPair p
```

and `p` is encoded with a `GADT`. In examples above, it's sliced into the
definitions.

You can also make dependent pairs with something else than a type as a first
  element. But then you have to read about
[singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons).

Comment: Is the `Typeable t` constraint inside the `CList` GADT meant to be a `c t` constraint? Otherwise wouldn't we be just tagging the list with a phantom parameter of kind `* -> Constraint`?